# Using IF and VLOOKUP to change font color of rows

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

[image: Screenshot of spreadsheets]

I have two excel spreadsheets and want to write a code that uses vlookup, match, and if such that when run it will check to see if there is a match between the price of the transaction and rate of the contract for each "contract agreement id" and if there is not a match it will turn the font on that row to red. For example rows 3, and 9 on the transaction page will turn red because either the price/rate does not match or there is not a contract for that transaction BUT row 9 on the contracts page is okay because you can have a contract without a transaction.

Comment: Sounds like conditional formatting using a formula.

Comment: Do you know what that code would be?

Comment: A word of caution.  This will be done using conditional formatting, as has been suggested.  But I would advise that one *never* places any complex logic in a conditional formatting formula.  Logic errors and especially circular references in a conditional formatting formulas are one the top, if not the single top risk for excel file corruption.   I would create a helper column "L" and have your formula populate column L with "Fail" or "Not Found".  Then use a very simple conditional format that if L is "not found" then the whole row is turned red.

Comment: In terms of the logic...  I don't think lookup/match is your answer.  I think you just want to use COUNTIFS because the match logic is already built into it.  COUNTIFS counts the number of rows were all of the multiple conditions are true.  In transaction sheet column L you would put a COUNTIFS that counts the number of rows in the contract table where the agreement IDs and the prices matched, and then your conditional format would simply check to see if Column L is 0.  You could just apply the red if col L = 0, or use an IF statement in L to make it something more readable like "Not Found".

Comment: see soln.  Matches would also work btw.

Answer (score 0):

Screenshots refer,

**Assumptions:**

Noting - some ambiguity in the Q - I make these assumptions:

- You *actually* intend to compare "Price" (col I, 1st pic) to "Rate" (col H, 2nd pic) for common contract IDs and expiry dates (as these are the only two factors by when Price/Rate differs in respective sheets/tables).
- If this is not the intention, then it should be an easy exercise to modify the lookup / matching criteria to the precise definition of correspondence desired (days/burger size/description whatever)

**Base fn**
formula - basic function underpinning conditional formatting function:

```
=IF(--ISNUMBER(MATCH(H4:H9&I4:I9,C4:C9&D4:D9,0)),J4:J9-E4:E9,"no match")
```

[image: Base function]

---

**Conditional formatting equations:**

1. For different prices (yellow) - assuming a matched contract ID and expiry date:

   =--(1*ABS(IF(--ISNUMBER(MATCH($H4:$H9&$I4:$I9,$C4:$C$9&$D4:$D9,0)),$J4:$J9-$E4:$E9,"no match"))>0)
2. For equal prices (assuming match):

   =(IF(--ISNUMBER(MATCH(H4:H9&I4:I9,C4:C9&D4:D9,0)),J4:J9-E4:E9,"no match")=0)

[image: Green conditional formatting - note to include bullets/dollar signs to fix the ranges now]

*For some reason conditional formatting equations do not appear to preserve the 'array' output - i.e. whereas you wouldn't ordinarily need to 'fix' ranges for 'spill'-type functions, you do now when using conditional formatting - just select range and press F4. fyi*

3. Paint entire region gray to begin with (process of elimination means that no equation required for this option 'no match').

*Note: in my example expiry dates were set to not necessarily match. In your sample data - I see there is a 1:1 match - this means you should be fine applying my formula as is / with minimal aleration (you would want to have this second condition because rates for the same product otherwise appear to vary according to expiry - if this is what you intend to determine then I recommend using an averageifs with everything else as is, if quantum is of interest - however, per one of the comments, you may only require a binary 'countifs' equation - notwithstanding the requirement for a second condition as part of the primary lookup key - if that makes sense...)*